# USB Drive not recognised by Ubuntu nor Windows

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, gparted, usb-drive, fdisk

My 64gb Sandisk Cruzer Glide Usb drive freezes my linux desktop partition tools such as GParted, and also tends to freeze windows partitioning applications. I cannot do anything to the usb drive other than using the command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=32
```

Any suggestions?. Also when I go to GParted, the message `end of file while reading /dev/sda` appears. How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried on a different computer?  The stick might just be defective.

Comment: I've tried it on a windows computer and my linux computer, it doesn't work on any computer. That usb was working before I used dd to write ubuntu to my usb

Comment: I know a usb can sometimes get corrupted due to writing an image to it, yet I have tried everything.

Comment: What do you do when the message appears? I.e. did you just start `gparted`, and saw the message, or does it appears when you're trying to create a partition? Also, unplug the drive, execute in the terminal `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, plug the drive, and add to the post all the output that would appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue and after doing a lot of research I found [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

Now please be sure to use this with extreme caution as you can end up accidentally formatting the wrong device. This occurred when Windows attempted to "Fix" a USB Drive that was plugged into a Linux system from before.